# PHP Convert ISO date to more readable format?

Tags: php, datetime

Just a simple question. How do I convert a PHP ISO time (like 2010-06-23T20:47:48-04:00) to something more readable? Is there a function already built in PHP? I've looked around but I haven't seen anything to convert times. If there's not a function, is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: you could trim the string from T or replace T with space and then trim from `-` (Z) if you need time. There is no other date more readable than ISO 8601 date format, specially if you are planning to share that date, worldwide. Everyone knows a date like `2020-10-09` means `9th Oct, 2020` but in some places of world `10/09/2020` is `10th Sep, 2020` and some other places `09th Oct, 2020`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$format = "d M Y"; //or something else that date() accepts as a format
date_format(date_create($time), $format);
```

Comment: Staring me in the face the whole time. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
echo date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2010-06-23T20:47:48-04:00") );
```

Format this part "Y-m-d H:i:s" using `format` from this documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Worth mentioning that if you need to support dates prior to 1970 then strtotime will not be the way to go. date_create uses the DateTime classes of PHP and will support older dates as well.

Comment: @strandmyr It actually works fine with older dates. `strtotime()` will return negative number. Maybe on window 32-bit or something like that it can return false, but I am not sure

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for the date function: http://php.net/function.date

Possibly paired with the strtotime function: http://php.net/function.strtotime

Comment: May work, but `date()` requires the timestamp to be an integer - therefore it won't work if the ISO time is already a string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try strftime

http://php.net/function.strftime

Answer (score 1):

[strptime()](http://php.net/function.strptime) converts a string containing a time/date with the format passed as second argument to the function. The return value is an array containing values for day, month, year, hour, minutes, and seconds; you can use those values to obtain a string representing the date in the format you like.

[strptime()](http://php.net/function.strptime) is available since PHP 5.1.0, while the class [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime.construct) is available since PHP 5.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo strftime("%b %e %Y at %l:%M %p", strtotime($ios));
```

will do

Answer (score 0):

For a short date try this:

```
$a_date = '2010-06-23T20:47:48-04:00';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($a_date));
```